# Prove that for every $m>0$ there exists an open covering of $\mathbb{Q}$ consists of countably many open intervals...

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Prove that for every $m>0$ there exists an open covering of $\mathbb{Q}$ consisting of countably many open intervals of total length less than or equal to $m.$ Does this covering have a finite subcovering?

I don't know where to start with this.

Comment: @bof I may have misheard, it seems weird that Q would be compact since it isn't bounded nor does each open covering have a finite sub covering. I'll remove that now

Comment: Perhaps you're supposed to use the fact that $\mathbb Q$ _isn't_ compact (as you've pointed out) to answer your second question.

EDIT: On second thought that seems like a rather unlikely pedagogical choice. Kabo's answer seems fine, though.

Comment: @DominickJoo : The fact that $\mathbb Q$ is not compact is not enough to entail that a PARTICULAR specified open cover lacks a finite subcover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true that the set of rational numbers is compact. It is not even bounded.

Arrange the set of all rationals in  a sequence $(r_1,r_2,...)$ and consider the intervals $(r_i-\frac m {2^{i+1}},r_i+\frac m {2^{i+1}})$. These intervals cover $\mathbb Q$ and have total length less than $m$.
  You cannot have a finite number of intervals of total length less than  $m$ that cover $\mathbb Q$. This is because the union of these interval is a bounded set but $\mathbb Q$  is not bounded.